# Alpahanumeric column natural sort in mysql where data is any combination of alphabets,number,special character

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, alphanumeric, natural-sort

I have following data

**Email**

```
0@gmail.com      
18@gmail.com      
1@gmail.com     
18@gmail.com  
55@gmail.com      
testproject2user1@gmail.com      
testproject2user10@gmail.com      
testproject22user1@gmail.com      
test!&project2user1@gmail.com
```

So I want to sort above data as

below like natural sorting in mysql

```
0@gmail.com      
1@gmail.com      
18@gmail.com      
55@gmail.com      
testproject2user1@gmail.com      
testproject2user10@gmail.com      
testproject22user1@gmail.com      
test!&project2user1@gmail.com
```

My attempts:

```
SELECT email FROM user
 ORDER BY email+0<>0 DESC, 
          email+0, email;

 SELECT email FROM user
 ORDER BY email REGEXP '^\d*[^\da-z&\.\' \-\"\!\@\#\$\%\^*()\;\:\<\>\,\?\/\~`\|_\-]' DESC,
          email+0, email
```

Comment: @sagi I tried this SELECT email 
FROM user 
ORDER BY email+0<>0 DESC, email+0, email;   another query with regular expression is          SELECT email 
FROM user
ORDER BY email REGEXP '^\d*[^\da-z&\.\' \-\"\!\@\#\$\%\^\*\(\)\;\:\<\>\,\?\/\~\`\|\_\-]' DESC, email+0, email

Comment: any solution about this?

Comment: @sagi any solution do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a set of user defined functions that split strings into a prefixed number and a rest component and use the numeric prefix to sort numerically and the rest component to sort alphabetically.

Comment: This is solution but not feasible solution because performance also need to consider

Comment: If need to fetch millions of records this solution is feasible?It might raise performance issue.

Comment: It all depends on the complexity of the work you need done. Ofcourse you could design using functions and write it all out into one single query/view/stored procedure before production. Either way, you should probably worry about getting it to work reliably before you worry about performance.